# Ошибка при открытии файла формата pkl

Tags: python, файлы, pickle

У меня есть папка расширения .tar в которой хранится информация о модели машинного обучения (веса, лосс и другие значения). Также в архиве имеется файл data.pkl, который как раз-таки содержит эту информацию. Мне необходимо открыть его и поменять некоторые ключи(пути, где обучалась модель).

```
import pickle


with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

Пытаясь выполнить это код, я получаю такую ошибку:

```
UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

Подскажите, как мне открыть данный файл?

Comment: Проверьте, что пытаетесь открыть файл той же версией Python, как и та, в которой он был создан.

Comment: И той же версией `pickle`

Comment: @CrazyElf, pickle - стандартный модуль, по идее гвоздями прибит к своей версии Python, атрибутов похожих на  version у него нет, так что не понятно, как определить, что версия та же.

Comment: @insolor Так то да. Единственно что, можно при записи указать `protocol=`, но обычно никто этого не делает. И более свежие версии по идее должны уметь читать записанное более старыми. Версия протокола определяется из файла при чтении. Так что скорее всего да - записано из более свежей версии питона, а читать пытаются из более старой.